# How to load a collection for best_in_place asynchronously?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

We use the in place editing JS library best_in_place (https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place)  heavily, even for lists with more then 1000 items.

Is there a way to load the 1000 items asynchronously?

What I imagine is, that if the users wants to change the value,
it clicks into the field which opens a search field and a list of the first 10 items.
When the user searches, the 10 items are fetched by AJAX from the server based on the search string.

Comment: The question is too broad.  Your best option is paging.  You don't want to elbow users in the eye with 1000 records.  For usability add a filter with paging.

Comment: yes, you are right. I just edited my question. Paging doesn't help as best_in_place is a inline editing library

Comment: What you want to do is have best_in_place work side by side with an autocomplete plugin.  Search for easy integration.  I will try to search for options.  To get better answers, attempt an implementation and ask about what specific issues you are having with the code.